# How to Create a Patch file on Mac OS X

Tags: ios, macos

In my iOS Application I want to create a patch file for the modified files to send it to Review Board.How can i generate a patch file in Mac OS by using Terminal

Comment: With the reviewboard, do you mean the AppStore review? That you do not send in a patch but the full app.

Comment: not appstore review,i need to send it to Client for the code review through Review Board

Comment: If you are using a code repository (like svn or git) you can send them a diff of the two relevant revisions.

Comment: How can i create the diff file from Xcode or from Terminal?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First check in the Xcode Downloads whether the Command Line Tools are downloaded or not. if not first download that and then follow the below procedure

In Terminal go to the directory where we need that Patch File and execute the Command    **svn diff > somename.patch** then you will get a patch file in that directory

Comment: I know it's 9 years later. I wonder why this is the accepted answer. The OP mentioned nothing about svn

Comment: I know this is 8 years later. The OP did mention `svn` in a follow-up comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20397345/how-to-create-a-patch-file-on-mac-os-x#comment30460037_20398186. "I want to create a diff file for the local folder and SVN folder and i'm using Xcode IDE"

Answer (score 21):

If you don't want to use VCS for creating patch then you can use `diff` tool.
You can create patch for one file using

```
diff -u original.c new.c > original.patch
```

Or

```
diff -rupN original/ new/ > original.patch
```

For entire folder

Comment: I want to create a diff file for the local folder and SVN folder and i'm using Xcode IDE

Comment: So, you have original sources in svn folder and your modified sources in another folder, right? Or you changed sources in svn folder?

Comment: If you're using SVN, you can just do <code>svn diff > whatever.patch</code> from your working copy.

Comment: @igoris Yes i have original sources in SVN and i have modified the local copy and i need diff file of these two

Comment: If your modified sources are in the SVN working copy then just use svn diff > whatever.patch (as stated by @Zydeco). If you've copied sources to another folder and then modified them, then use diff command

Comment: @igoris can you please share me the Terminal Commands for this

Comment: Terminal commands for what? I already gave you a command to generate a patch from two folders (diff -rupN original/ new/ > original.patch) and @Zydeco gave a command to generate a patch from svn working copy (svn diff > whatever.patch).